# Exibir 5 últimos resultados postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Preciso exibir os 5 últimos resultados de uma consulta, porém faço essa consulta duas vezes pois preciso mudar a cláusula where, para retornar os valores que preciso.

Pensei em algo como por exemplo:

```
SELECT id, project_id, name, subject FROM "issues" where project_id = 94 

UNION ALL 
    SELECT id, project_id, name, subject FROM "issues" where project_id = 95 

limit 5
```

Porém não funcionou...
Existe alguma maneira de fazer uma consulta apenas e mudar a sua cláusula para exibir todos os registros que preciso ?

Comment: você não poderia fazer assim: `SELECT id, project_id, name, subject from "issues" where project_id = 94 and project_id = 95 order by id desc limit 5` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver teu problema você pode usar a cláusula `IN`. Ela permite que seja informado um conjunto de valores para um teste. Nesse caso, sua consulta 
ficaria:

```
SELECT id, project_id, name, subject FROM "issues" where project_id IN (94, 95) limit 5
```

O `IN` testa se o valor do project_id está entre algum dos valores informados (94 ou 95) e se estiver lista nos resultados.

Comment: Perfeito @Giuliana, pensamos juntos, estava fazendo um teste agora antes de ver as respostas aqui do site e vi que chegamos a mesma conclusão, obrigado !!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um comando **SQL** que atenda a sua necessidade:

```
SELECT id, project_id, name, subject from "issues" where project_id = 94 and project_id = 95 order by id desc limit 5
```

Onde `where project_id = 94 and project_id = 95` já verifica as duas condições.
`Order by id desc` pega as ultimas informações primeiro.
`Limit 5` Pega suas ultimas 5 no caso.

Comment: Já havia tentado isso antes, porém não funcionou, pois não tem como um registro ter o **ID 94** e **ID 95** ao mesmo tempo, logo não retornará nenhum registro.

Comment: Ah bom, é que como isso não estava no escopo da pergunta acabei não considerando isso

Comment: De qualquer forma isso não é possível :S, não tem como um registro ter dois **ID** diferentes, o **ID** é único